# From a UWP app, can I open a link in Edge without opening a new tab?

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app that is launching links in Edge but every time I launch a url, it creates a new tab in the edge browser.

My question is: Is it possible from a UWP app to launch Edge and open a link in a tab that is already open in the Edge browser?

Is there a way that I can name the tab when I open the first web link and then later reference that tab ID or name?

Thanks!

Comment: you can also open same link in your app web browser control

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Yeah that would give me alot more control. Unfortunately for my purposes I would need to open them in the Edge app

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible from a UWP app to launch Edge and open a link in a tab that is already open in the Edge browser?

Microsoft Edge does not support `Tab` manual management. When launch it with link, it will create new tab to display. But Internet Explorer support that open link in same tap. You could refer the follow setting.

[image]

> Is there a way that I can name the tab when I open the first web link and then later reference that tab ID or name?

The Tab's name comes from page `Title` automatically . You could not name the tab manually.

[image]

For flexible requirement, you could use `WebView` Control. For more please refer [`Webview` official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view).

Comment: Thanks. I mean I would like to be able to programmatically tell Edge to open a URL in a specific tab or use the existing  open tab without going into the browser settings

Comment: Currently, Edge does not support it. but you could use IE like the above.

Comment: @Nico zhu, It seems the Edge still not support it, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

It not easy to tell IE what to do in an UWP app. Actually you can create a desktop application to launch IE and you can control the IE how to open the URL.

How to active the desktop application from UWP APP you can refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher