# How can I get my C# UWP app to REFRESH my browser page, instead of opening a new tab?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, xamarin, uwp, microsoft-edge

A partner company has a web app that opens my Xamarin UWP app using a URI to perform a function. When this function completes, my app will open a URL that the web app provides, which is the same URL which initiated the opening of my App.

This Xamarin app is currently deployed in iOS, and when using the Safari browser, everything works how we would like:  The browser tab which "called" my app is "opened" and refreshed, showing the data that my app has posted.

But, in Windows with both Chrome and Edge, a NEW tab is opened with the link. This is inconvient to the user, as each of these will result in a new tab and chaos may reign.

Searching stackoverflow, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50847949/1758350) asked several years ago regarding Edge -- with no solution other than "you can't really do what you want".  Is it possible "in general", or is there a way with Chrome? Is there any update?

Comment: I believe you would have to pass the event to the web page session via their web server. Either by refreshing a url, or a web socket. eg this is how OAuth device flows work.

Comment: This sounds right in some way to me.  But I don't control the that part of the system.   I wonder how I could best describe to them what needs to be done (IANAWD == I am not a web developer).   Right now, I POST the data to them, the OPEN a URL they have given me.  Almost sounds like when they get my POST, they should refresh the page on their own.  I wonder how focus would go back to the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ***LaunchUriAsync***, here's the sample code:

```
using Windows.System;

Uri uri = ...; // The URI provided by the web app

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx-web://" + uri));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is the wrong side.  I have no problem with my app getting launched by user clicking a URL link on a website.  My issue is when my app is "done", "launching" the browser again -- it creates a new tab, which will be tough on the user.